# Does .NET Core HttpClient have the concept of interceptors?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like to wrap some timing logic around all calls made through HttpClient from my ASP.NET Core app, including calls made from 3rd party libraries.

Does `HttpClient` in .NET Core have something I can plug into to run some code on every request?

Comment: Are you referring to middlewares?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

Comment: No. If I have an ASP.NET Core app that contains a library that calls another server through HTTP, how can I know how long it took for that library to call the other server. Other technologies (Angular) have the concept of interceptors where you can receive a callback whenever an outgoing HTTP request is made. Does .NET Core have this? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it does. `HttpClient` produces a HTTP request via `DelegatingHandler` chain. To intercept the `HttpClient` request, you can add a derived handler with overrided `SendAsync` method  to that chain.

Usage:

```cs
var handler = new ExampleHttpHandler(fooService);

var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var response = await client.GetAsync("http://google.com");
```

Implementation:

```cs
public class ExampleHttpHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    //use this constructor if a handler is registered in DI to inject dependencies
    public ExampleHttpHandler(FooService service) : this(service, null)
    {
    }

    //Use this constructor if a handler is created manually.
    //Otherwise, use DelegatingHandler.InnerHandler public property to set the next handler.
    public ExampleHttpHandler(FooService service, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
    {
        //the last (inner) handler in the pipeline should be the "real" one.
        //To make a HTTP request, create a HttpClientHandler instance.
        InnerHandler = innerHandler ?? new HttpClientHandler();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //add any logic here
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

BTW, I recommend moving as much business logic out of a custom handler as possible to simplify unit-testing it. Also, check `HttpClient` lifetime [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines) for best practices in .NET http client creation.

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies to the entire question. It looks like a way to have a callback for every request in your own code, which would use ExampleHttpHandler. But I don't see how it would affect the behaviour of the internals of a third party library you use.

Comment: @Zastai It depends on library. A good one should accept an external `HttpClient` instance or a handler as optional parameter. For example, `Flurl` gives such possibility.